# SublimeText Multi-line RegEx Search/Replace difficulties

Tags: regex, replace

I have a number configuration files which need some formatting love because different folks/different strokes, right. I run across this problem often enough that I would really like to automate this process and boy is it a lulu.

I'm not unfamiliar with RegEx and have some success, just not a complete success. (My 93% solution is at the end.) Even if this ends up requiring a couple of passes to complete that's fine too. (Help with that macro would be great as well.)

Here is a specific example (it's from a mod with MIT license nothing proprietary):

```
PART:NEEDS[blackheart]
{
    name = stickerIDFLAGSStandard
    module = Part
    author = vexillar
    MODEL
    {
        model = blackheart/Parts/stickerh/model
        texture = placeholder , IDFlags/Standard/Flags/A
    }
    rescaleFactor = 1
    node_attach = -0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0
    TechRequired = start
    entryCost = 6200
    cost = 10
    category = Utility
    subcategory = 0
    title = Place Anywhere Sticker Type A (IDFlags Standard)
    manufacturer = Blackheart's Vinyls
    description = Have you ever felt like you needed to show the world how many companies cared about your program? No? Well now you can with this vinyl sticker! Attach anywhere on your ship and you should be good to go.
    attachRules = 0,1,0,0,1
    mass = 0.01
    dragModelType = default
    maximum_drag = 0
    minimum_drag = 0
    angularDrag = 1
    crashTolerance = 12
    maxTemp = 2000
    heatConductivity = 20
    skinMassPerArea = 20
    explosionPotential = 0
    PhysicsSignificance = 0
    bulkheadProfiles = srf
    tags = sticker decal
    
MODULE
{
 name = FSmeshSwitch
 moduleID = 0
 buttonName = Next Shape
 previousButtonName = Previous Shape
 objectDisplayNames = Flat;Size1;Size2;Size3
 objects = stickerflat, colliderflat;sticker125, collider125;sticker250, collider250;sticker375, collider375
 updateSymmetry = true
}

MODULE
{
    name = FStextureSwitch2
    moduleID = 5328
    nextButtonText = Next ID Flag/Decal
    prevButtonText = Previous ID Flag/Decal
    statusText = Current
    textureRootFolder = IDFlags/Standard/Flags/
    textureNames = +0;+1;+2;+3;+4;+5;+6;+7;+8;+9;00;01;02;03;04;05;06;07;08;09;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;24;38;54;63;66;A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;J;K;L;M;N;O;P;Q;R;S;T;U;V;W;X;Y;Z
    objectNames = stickerflat;sticker125;sticker250;sticker375 //--don't change this
    textureDisplayNames = 0;1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;00;01;02;03;04;05;06;07;08;09;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;18;19;20;24;38;54;63;66;A;B;C;D;E;F;G;H;I;J;K;L;M;N;O;P;Q;R;S;T;U;V;W;X;Y;Z
    debugMode = false
    showInfo = false
}
DRAG_CUBE
{
    none = True
}
}
```

What I want to do is S&R the snert out of these files to create a ***properly*** nested structure (4sp tabs) that doesn't destroy code-folding. I understand that multiple passes will be required to massage the structure (remove the leading space or inserting an additional line between MODULEs.) Now, I've been able to achieve what I want ALMOST exactly with this:

Search:  `(MODULE\n)(\{\n)((^.+$\n)+)(\}\n)`

Replace: `\t$1\t{\n\t$3\t}\n`

Unfortunately, only the first line of code inside the squiggly-brackets gets indented; so, this ...

```
MODULE
{
name = FSmeshSwitch
moduleID = 0
buttonName = Next Shape
previousButtonName = Previous Shape
objectDisplayNames = Size1;Size2;Size3
objects = sticker125, collider125;sticker250, collider250;sticker375, collider375
updateSymmetry = true
}
```

becomes this ...

```
    MODULE
    {
        name = FSmeshSwitch
moduleID = 0
buttonName = Next Shape
previousButtonName = Previous Shape
objectDisplayNames = Flat;Size1;Size2;Size3
objects = stickerflat, colliderflat;sticker125, collider125;sticker250, collider250;sticker375, collider375
updateSymmetry = true
    }
```

I'm beginning to think I'm barking up the wrong tree and this ask is just a little beyond S&R.

Comment: You are adding a character before a whole match and that will only add it before name only. You could for example align the key values inside the braces like this `(?:^(MODULE\R{(?=[^{}]*\R}))|\G(?!^))\R\h*([^=\r\n]+\h*=\h*[^=\r\n]+)` and then replace with `$1\n    $2` See https://regex101.com/r/ELR5Ms/1/